# "500 Internal Server Error" Apache notebook Zeppelin on Azure Hdinsight

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, jupyter, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to write a spark application(in scala) in Azure HDInsight to extract information from a log line using regular expression. 
the regular expression is this:

```
val patt1="""(?:(\w+) (\w+) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\S+)  (\w+) \[([^]]+)\]   \((.*)\) - \[(\w+)\](?:\[(\w+)\])?\[(\w+)\]\[(\w+)\]\[\w+\]\[([^]]+)\](?:.*\[(.+)\]}))""".r
```

The pattern is correct, because if I use Jupyter notebook, or work in local in eclipse everything works and I am able to extract the data from the logs.

The problem is just when I try to use Zeppelin notebook instead of Jupyter when I write the patt1 as a string (without .r) give me this strange error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I also tried to import scala.util.matching.Regex before to build the regex but the error is the same. I think there is something in the triple quote or in the format that zeppelin doesn't allow, but I can't understand what. Can anyone help me, please? I want to use Zeppelin instead of Jupyter because I think give better visualization of sparksql queries.

But if i try to write a simple pattern as `patt= """abc.*""".r` there is no error.

EDIT:i tried several time to write regular expression in Zeppelin and it seems that the problem is with capturing groups as (\d) (\w) etc. Zeppelin scala interpret(Livy) don't take them.
But the same identical regex works perfectly in jupyter.
i'm new in scala and maybe i miss something very ease.Please help me

Comment: paste the exception stacktrace which caused the  internal server error

Comment: there is no exception stacktrace, just this error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I just replaced all the `\` with `\\` and it works perfectly.
Seems that Livy interpeter does not accept single `\` in scala regex but accepts `\\` and then convert to `\`.